# C++ --- Shouldn't these mathematical functions/constants be undefined?

Tags: c++, boost

I would not expect the following code that prints the value of sin(pi/2) to work, without the inclusion of an additional header:

```cs
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << sin(0.5*M_PI) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

and, as expected, upon compilation I get an error reading `‘sin’ was not declared in this scope` and a similar error for the use of `M_PI`.

However, I am confused by the fact that if I include seemingly *any* [boost library](http://www.boost.org) header, take just for example the `lexical_cast.hpp`, and instead run

```cs
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::cout << sin(0.5*M_PI) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

then the code works and it prints `1`.

Why should including this boost header, which contains no definition of `M_PI` or `sin()`, allow this constant and function to be defined? Shouldn't I need to include a header, like `math.h` that includes these things for this to work?

Comment: the C++ standard allows any header to include any other standard header (or part thereof); and also , names specified as being in `namespace std` are allowed to actually be in global namespace but injected into namespace std. So your original program could even compile on some conforming implementations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it should work that way.

The boost headers you tried all have implicit dependencies (pow(), modf(), fmod(), log() etc).

This is a common thing in the C++ compilation model. Nothing to be alarmed by.

> Guideline: always *explicitly* include the headers you directly depend on. And only those.

This prevents portability issues on platforms where the library header dependency tree differs e.g. `<algorithms>` and `<numeric>` aren't implicitly included with some other standard library headers (e.g. MSVC)